# Question on loading the pretrained weights in another trained model

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch

I work with videos (input shape [batch,channels,frames,height,width]) and I designed a video classification model in which I used pretrained ResNet50 that extract features from each frame separately (2D convolution) and then the model stacks the extracted features from all the frames. I trained my model on a video classification dataset and now I want to use my trained model for another task. In this regard, my question is that since I loaded the pretrained weights of the ResNet50 in my model, for using my trained new model and loading its checkpoints in another task should I also load the weights of the ResNet50 in my script?

```
import os
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
from torchvision.models import resnet50, ResNet50_Weights
import torch.nn.functional as F
from collections import OrderedDict
num_class = 25
class BasicConv3d(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, in_planes, out_planes, kernel_size, stride, padding=0):
        super(BasicConv3d, self).__init__()
        self.conv = nn.Conv3d(in_planes, out_planes, kernel_size=kernel_size, stride=stride, padding=padding, bias=False)
        self.bn = nn.BatchNorm3d(out_planes, eps=1e-3, momentum=0.001, affine=True)
        self.relu = nn.ReLU()

    def forward(self, x):
        
            
        x = self.conv(x)
        x = self.bn(x)
        x = self.relu(x)
        return x
    
    

class Interpolate_1(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, size, mode):
        super(Interpolate_1, self).__init__()
        self.interp = nn.functional.interpolate
        self.size = size
        self.mode = 'bilinear'
        
    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.interp(x, size=self.size, mode=self.mode, align_corners=False)
        return x


len_temporal = 16

__all__ = ['Spatial_Encoder']

class Spatial_Encoder(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, pretrained=True):
        super(Spatial_Encoder, self).__init__()
        
        self.fc_1 = nn.Sequential(nn.Conv3d(2048, 25, kernel_size=1, stride=1, bias=True))
        if torch.cuda.is_available():
            self.fc_1.cuda()
        
        
        
        self.featureExtractor = resnet50(weights=ResNet50_Weights.IMAGENET1K_V2)
        if torch.cuda.is_available():
            self.featureExtractor.cuda()
        
        self.activation = {}
        def get_activation(name):
            def hook(model, input, output):
                self.activation[name] = output.detach()
            return hook

    
        self.featureExtractor.layer4.register_forward_hook(get_activation('layer4'))
        
        self.conv_t_1 = BasicConv3d(2048, 2048, kernel_size=(3,1,1), stride=(2,1,1), padding=(1,0,0))
        if torch.cuda.is_available():
            self.conv_t_1.cuda()
                
        self.conv_t_2 = BasicConv3d(2048, 2048, kernel_size=(3,1,1), stride=(2,1,1), padding=(1,0,0))
        if torch.cuda.is_available():
            self.conv_t_2.cuda()
        self.conv_t_3 = BasicConv3d(2048, 2048, kernel_size=(3,1,1), stride=(2,1,1), padding=(1,0,0))
        if torch.cuda.is_available():
            self.conv_t_3.cuda()
        self.conv_t_4 = BasicConv3d(2048, 2048, kernel_size=(3,1,1), stride=(2,1,1), padding=(1,0,0))
        if torch.cuda.is_available():
            self.conv_t_4.cuda()

        
        self.fc = nn.Sequential(nn.Conv3d(2048, num_class, kernel_size=1, stride=1, bias=True),)
        self.avgpool = nn.AdaptiveAvgPool3d((1, 1, 1))          
        
    def forward_features(self, x,len_temporal):   
        
        image_s = []
        features_4 = []

        for i in range(len_temporal):
            image_s = x[:,:,i:i+1,:,:]
            
            frame = self.featureExtractor(image_s.squeeze(2))
            layer4_output_Temporal_att = self.activation['layer4']
            features_4.append(layer4_output_Temporal_att)                                 
        return torch.stack(features_4,dim=2)




    def forward(self, x):
        # x.shape : [batch_size,channels,frames,height,width]
        
        Spatial_features_4 = self.forward_features(x,len_temporal = x.size(2))   # [batch, 2048, 16, 4, 4]
        
        y = self.conv_t_1(Spatial_features_4.cuda())                      #([batch, 2048, 8, 4, 4])
        y = self.conv_t_2(y)                                              # [batch , 2048, 4, 4, 4])
        y = self.conv_t_3(y)                                              # [batch, 2048, 2, 4, 4])
        y = self.conv_t_4(y)                                              # [batch, 2048, 1, 4, 4])

        y = F.avg_pool3d(y, (1, y.size(3), y.size(4)), stride=1)         # ([batch, 2048, 1, 1, 1])

        y = self.fc_1(y)                                                 # ([batch, 25, 1, 1, 1])
             
        y = y.view(y.size(0), y.size(1), y.size(2))                      # ([batch, 25, 1])
        
        logits = torch.mean(y, 2)                                        # ([batch, 25])
        return logits
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

If I understood correctly, you trained your `Spatial_Encoder` model on features extracted by ResNet50 model with pretrained weights, with a video classification task

If this is correct, each time you are using this trained `Spatial_Encoder` you will need to first feed the video data through the same ResNet50 with the same weights, and then through your trained model. If you want to use other input features (for example by changing the feature extractor), you will have to train it again on the new features, or at the very least finetune it starting from the `Spatial_Encoder` weights that you already have.

For other tasks, you could add another model after, but the video will still have to go through the ResNet50 model that you used during training, your trained `Spatial_Encoder` and the other model you add.